# set value of a property of an anonymous type using reflection / TypeDescriptor is it possible?

Tags: c#, reflection, anonymous-types, typedescriptor

I tried using TypeDescriptor and the value is not changing, and via reflection I get an error that there is no setter for that property

Comment: You'll get better answers if you post some code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Did you read the error? If the property has no setter, you cannot set it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set value for property of an anonymous object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441420/how-to-set-value-for-property-of-an-anonymous-object)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C# anonymous types are immutable, and their properties cannot be changed.

If you *really* want to, you could set the backing field using reflection, but it would be a bad idea.