# Anonymous types are immutable, structure or full object?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, anonymous-types

[set value of a property of an anonymous type using reflection / TypeDescriptor is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765367/set-value-of-a-property-of-an-anonymous-type-using-reflection-typedescriptor-i)

According to @Slaks ,

> C# anonymous types are immutable, and their properties cannot be
>   changed.

example :

```
dynamic p  = new {aaa="1", bbb="2"};
```

my question is , **What** is immutable ? ( structure , values , whole world ?)

the **structure** of

```
{ 
          something (in type of string) 
          ,
         something (in type of string ) 
    }
```

(meaning - the structure is immutable - and i cant change its structure)

**or**

```
 { 
          something called aaa (in type of string) 
          ,
         something called bbb (in type of string ) 
    }
```

**or**

the **whole** world :

```
  { 
      something (in type of string + value of 1) 
      ,
     something (in type of string + value of 2) 
}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immutable means it cannot change.

The structure *or* the values, in this case.

The type of `p` will always be two `string` properties - one called `aaa` with the value `"1"` and the other one called `bbb` with the value `"2"`.

You cannot add members to this anonymous type, nor can you change the values of the properties.

Comment: I can read its value via `xxx.GetType().GetProperty("aaa").GetValue(xxx,null)` , Can I also set it value via Refleaction ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Not sure. Looks like a fun little test ;)

Comment: You cannot set the value via reflection, the world is immutable!

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski - Things that _should_ be immutable can be changed through reflection. Seeing as you can access _private_ members of a class through reflection, even if you never expose a mutator for it, reflection will allow you to change it.

Comment: Anonymous properties have no setter and they also don't set a private field. `GetFields` is 0. Trying to set a value to the property with reflection, will give you `TargetInvokationException` [Property set method not found.]

Comment: @RoyiNamir - The automatically generated classes doesn't create a setter for the property and I think the generated backing field gets a name that cannot be easily reference. For all intents, it does make it difficult to use reflection to mutate the anonymous type.

Comment: Actually is possible to mutate an anonymous type:

`dynamic p = new {aaa="1", bbb="2"}; foreach(var f in p.GetType().GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic|System.Reflection‌​.BindingFlags.Instance)) f.SetValue(p,"hello"); Console.WriteLine(p.aaa);`

Comment: @Alberto - With reflection, sure.